# Resample(up sample or down sample) the images using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm using 'image_dataset_from_directory' to load my images. This will give a path to the images folder. If my images folder has two classes, class A has 500 images and class B have 300 images. I want to upsample the class B to 500 images when I load the images using TensorFlow, so I can have a balanced training dataset. What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use augmentation to generate those 200 missing images.
For example, rotate the first 200 images by 90°.
implemented in this code.

```
import os
import cv2

path_to_folder = "path_to_your_class_B_folder"

list_items_in_dir = os.listdir(path_to_folder)


for index, item in enumerate(list_items_in_dir):

    if index >= 200:
        break

    img = cv2.imread(path_to_folder+"/"+item)
    cv2.rotate(img, 90)

    cv2.imwrite(path_to_folder+"/"+item, img)
```

For that, you will need cv2
which can be installed by using this cmd

```
pip install opencv-python
```

You can also randomize the angle of rotation:

```
import os
import cv2
import random

path_to_folder = "path_to_your_class_B_folder"

list_items_in_dir = os.listdir(path_to_folder)


for index, item in enumerate(list_items_in_dir):

    if index >= 200:
        break

    img = cv2.imread(path_to_folder+"/"+item)
    cv2.rotate(img, random.randint)

    cv2.imwrite(path_to_folder+"/"+item, img)
```

If you want to use [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation) itself it is capable too to augment your data